# ASP.NET SqlDataSource set SessionParameter programmatically

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a StoredProcedure called "usp_posts_getall" and it has 1 parameter called "@thisCategoryID"

in my "thisCategoryID", any values other than 0(zero) will return all the records in my Posts table.

Now I have a category menu items and each time I select, I set the value in my Session name called "SelectedCID".

So, How do I ...
Create a SessionParameter Programmatically in SqlDataSource?

---

UPDATE:
ok. I got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a session parameter that's used by the SqlDataSource, then you can set the value in the session, e.g in `Page_Load()`:

```
Session["thisCategoryID"] = theCategoryId;
```

(am I misunderstanding the question?)

Ok, update:

I think you can create an event handler for the `SqlDataSource.OnSelecting` event. In that handler, you can access the `Parameters` collection of the datasource and can add another Parameter to it. I currently cannot test the following code, so it might not be fully correct, but I hope you see the idea:

```
SqlDataSource1_OnSelecting(SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs args)
{
  var param = new Parameter("@thisCatagoryID");
  param.DefaultValue = Session["SelectedCID"]; 
  SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(param);  
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the parameter declaratively in the markup, e.g:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ...>
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="thisCategoryID" SessionField="SelectedCID"
      DefaultValue="0" />
    ...
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: iiiiiiiyeah M4N :) What I was asking was if how to programatically create a SessionParamater. revising the question.